# What's the best way to have an Rails model with associations but no database table for the main object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example, I have an account object.  I store that account object in an external service called the accounts service.  But I would like to associate accounts stored in the external service with local application preferences.

To be more specific, let's say the association is payment methods.  Accounts can have multiple payment methods.  I don't want the payment methods stored in the external service but rather the consuming application.  So I will have a table called account_payment_methods which will have an account id that is mapped to the external service account and a payment method id mapped to a local payment_method table.

I have an AccountPaymentMethod model and I could just use that but it would be nice to be able to do `account.payment_methods << PaymentMethod.first` or something like that.

Is there a known method out of the box or will I be writing this functionality myself?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Ryan bates covered this some time ago in this [screen-cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model). I am quite sure this will work in your scenario. Make sure you set the correct primary/foreign key attributes while specifying the associations.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3.2+, you may want to look at [this](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless) gem instead. The Table-less models RailsCast won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on where you want the join data to live.

If the info will live in the Accounts service:

I don't think you can have associations on non-ActiveRecord::Base-subclass classes, short of hacking them in from the ActiveRecord internals (by making your own subclasses of HasManyAssociation, that read your stored attributes.) So you might be a bit out of luck there.

If you want the info to live in your normal db:

I would probably have an AccountBridge model which maps the Account to the appropriate tables, and put the associations there; also proxying the account's methods to the account object. Then I'd have the objects which would nominally `have_{one,many} :account(s)` secretly proxy to AccountBridge, and have the actual foreign keys of the relationship.